# iOS Calculate speed of device using Core Motion

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I'm trying to calculate speed of physical device

In google i got

1. Using via `CLLocationManager`// I DON'T want to use
2. Using `UIAccelerometer` class : DEPECRATED

Upto now i have tried like this

```
    func coreMotion() { // CALLING FROM VIEW DID LOAD
            if self.motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
               self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.5
               self.motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!,
                                                           withHandler: { [weak self] (deviceMotion, error) -> Void in

                    if let error = error {
                        print("ERROR : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }

                    if let deviceMotion = deviceMotion {
                        self?.handleDeviceMotionUpdate(deviceMotion)
                    }
               })
            } else {
                print("WHAT THE HELL")
            }
        }

 func handleDeviceMotionUpdate(_ deviceMotion: CMDeviceMotion) {
        let attitude = deviceMotion.attitude
        let roll = self.degrees(attitude.roll)
        let pitch = self.degrees(attitude.pitch)
        let yaw = self.degrees(attitude.yaw)
        let accl = deviceMotion.userAcceleration
        self.calculateSpeed(accl)
        self.previousAccl = accl
        print("Roll: \(roll), Pitch: \(pitch), Yaw: \(yaw)")
        print("ACCELRATION: \(accl.x) \(accl.y) \(accl.z)")
    }

    func degrees(_ radians: Double) -> Double {
        return 180 / Double.pi * radians
    }
```

I'm getting acceleration object as well i.e userAcceleration
How can i calculate speed from that?

Comment: you can measure _acceleration_ then calculate the _speed_ based on those values and _time_.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the speed of the device, there is two possibilities for you :

1 - by approximating the derivative function of the position : with two position and the time between those two position you can estimate the speed.

2 - or compute a primitive of the acceleration. But take into account that this method will give you the correct speed value only if you know the speed à t_*0* (the begining of your measures)

But if you insist on doing it using acceleration you can compute speed at t_i (where i is the number of update you received from the accelerometer)

speed(t_*i*) = speed(t_*i-1*) + acceleration(t_*i*) * (t_*i* - t_*i-1*)
and speed(t_*0*) is supposed to be known

that way you must at each update from the accelerometer do
`speed = speed + acceleration * (lastUpdateTime - currentTime)`

[Edit]

this is indeed like you mentioned it in the comments only one dimension if you wish to compute speed for all three dimensions you will have to do this three time once for each axis

`speedX = speedX + accelerationX * (lastUpdateTime - currentTime)`

`speedY = speedY + accelerationY * (lastUpdateTime - currentTime)`

`speedZ = speedZ + accelerationZ * (lastUpdateTime - currentTime)`

And you will need to have knowledge of speedX/Y/Z at t_*0* to initialise your var at the correct value.

Comment: this answer is valid for any number of dimensions using an orthogonal mark, you just ave to do this for each axis.